# How to auto load a smarty plugin

Tags: php, smarty

We have a plugin for a PHP script with Smarty template engine,

It can be used in template files with {plugin_name} but that requires making sure this is on every single template file, the question is:

> is there a way to auto-load this plugin whenever the scripts loads?

Script is not open source, but Smarty and it's files (such as Smarty.class.php etc) are not encrypted.

### Edit

All I need to do is to auto-load a Smarty Plugin (which has small interaction with database) before template files load, is this possible/achievable with Smarty files only? (script itself in encrypted, but Smarty_Compiler.class.php, Smarty.class.php, Config_File.class.php, and other smarty core functions are open source)

Comment: Can you be more specific? what does this plugin do?

Comment: @Borgtex Any function, even `function test(){//Some Action with database}` , which can be used in template like {test}, the question is how to auto-load this before smarty loads template files (so it's run before template is displayed). I can already do it by putting {test} on top of every template file.

Comment: If the plugin runs before the template is displayed and does not modify it, why don't just execute the function in your php file before calling the template?

Comment: @Borgtex This is a smarty plugin, PHP script code is encrypted

Comment: But what it does? adds content to the template?, i.e. when you put <p>{plugin_name}</p> in the template the output is <p>This is the output</p>?

Comment: @Borgtex Not necessarily, you can simply use return ''; in plugin to return nothing, our function is doing some action with database

Comment: It's important because smarty has different types of plugins, like prefilters, postfilters, etc. Anyway... read about it at http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins

Comment: True, but like I said all this does is interaction with database, no output at all, like `UPDATE table SET count=count+1 WHERE id=1` simple as that, but we really need it to be auto-loaded before templates, any way thanks for your help, seems there is no auto load or you would've point it out already

Comment: What version of Smarty are you running? 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: @Tom it is smarty version 2.x, but I can upgrade to 3.x if necessary (I once tested and replacing the entire Smarty folder can upgrade smarty version to 3)

Comment: @Vladimir are you talking about pre-filters  by any chance?

Comment: @TAS I read them now and the guide says pre-filters are good for actions such as removing unwanted comments etc, do you think (based on what I explained) this is best way for our case?

Comment: Can't you use a prefilter plugin? Or otherwise, extend Smarty class, and do your business in the in extended class constructor?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the Smarty version you're using.

With Smarty 3 you can do :

```
$smarty = new Smarty();
$smarty->setTemplatesDir(....);
$smarty->addPluginsDir('/path/to/your/plugins');
... stuff.
$smarty->display('template.tpl');
```

See also: https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.add.plugins.dir.tpl

With Smarty2 I think you need to do something more like this -

https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/api.register.function.tpl

Or, you drop your function into the libs/plugins directory with the right file name and function name ...